# Loading a polymorphic resource in the controller to build nested polymorphic objects on

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a structure that looks like this:

Conferences has one about_module and one speaker_module with a polymorphic relationship

Both about_module and speaker_module has people with a polymorphic relationship

```
class Conference < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :about_module, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :about_module

  has_one :speaker_module, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :about_module
end


class AboutModule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true

  has_many :people, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people, allow_destroy: true
end


class SpeakerModule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true

  has_many :people, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people, allow_destroy: true
end


class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order(:position) }
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end
```

So when build a new person in the PersonController, i need to now which module to build it on. The problem is that i don't know how to access the parent polymorphic model.

For example:

/admin/conferences/:conference_id/speaker_module/people/new

/admin/conferences/:conference_id/about_module/people/new

The conference_id gets passed in the param, but i don't know which module it is.

In PeopleController#new I want load the corresponding module dynamically so I can call

```
@person = module.people.build
```

Of course i can overwrite my routes to include a resource type and id for the modules, like

```
/admin/conferences/:conference_id/:resource_type/:resource_id/people/new
```

But there must be a better way to do it?

In routes:

```
resources :conferences do

  resource :about_module do
    resources :people
  end

  resource :speaker_module do
    resources :people
  end
end
```